# ¿Cómo resuelvo el error id returned 1 exit status?

Tags: c++, id

Me dejaron de tarea hacer este programa que tenemos que imprimir hospitales de 3 diferentes zonas, y cada uno tiene distintas áreas, en ellas usé números aleatorios para llenar la matriz, sin embargo, lo único que me da es el error id returned, y no sé como solucionarlo, agradecería sí me dijeran mi error. Ya que he utilizado punteros, y no sé sí mis variables estan bien redireccionadas, utilice vector y matriz dinámica, aparte de que implementé el uso de variables globales.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
                  
void llenar(int *, int**, int);
void calcular(int *, int**, int, int, int &, float &);
void imprimir(int *, int**, int, int, int, float, string);

int main () {
    srand(time(0));
    string zonas[]={"SUR","NORTE", "CENTRO"};
    int hosp[]={3,5,7};
    int area[]={4,6,5};
    int *paci = new int[1]; // declaro vector dinamico
    int **matriz = new int *[1]; // declara matriz dinamico
    int suma;
    float prom;
    
        for(int i=0;i<3; i++){
        paci= new int[hosp[i]]; // redmimensiono vector 
        llenar(paci, matriz, hosp[i]);
        calcular(paci, matriz, hosp[i], area[i], suma, prom);
        imprimir(paci, matriz, hosp[i], area[i], suma, prom, zonas[i]);
    } 
} // fin de main

void imprimir (int *paci, int **matriz, int dim, int dimo, int suma, float prom, string nomZona){
    cout << "Zona: " << nomZona << endl;
    cout << "Hospital\tArea1\tArea2\tArea3\tArea4\tArea5\tArea6\tTotal\tProm"<< endl;
    for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dimo; j++){
            cout << matriz [i][j]<< "\t";
        }
        cout << paci[i]<< endl;
    }
    cout << "el promedio es: "<< prom << endl;
} // fin de imprimir
    

void calcular(int *paci, int **matriz, int dim, int dimo, int &suma, float &prom){
    for (int i=0; i<dim; i++){
        suma=0;
        for (int j=0; j<dimo; j++){
        suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
        }
        paci[i]=suma;
        prom = prom + suma;
    }
    prom = prom / dim; 
} // fin de calcular

void llenar(int *paci, int **matriz, int dim, int dimo){

    for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dimo; j++){
            matriz[i][j]= 1+rand()%30;
        }
    }
}// fin de llenar
```

Comment: Mira cuantos parametros recive tu funcion `llenar` y mira cuantos le pasas, al pasarle menos del que cencesitas el compilador busca en la pila otro elemento, que para nuestra desgracia puede ser `IP` del programa y nunca terminará porque se perdio el puntero a la siguiente instruccion, ¿Porque el compilador no me lanza error? porque lo linkeaste con menos parametro del que necesitas: Lo que le pasas `void llenar(int*,int**,int);` lo que necesita: `void llenar(int* paci,int** matris, int dim,int dimo);`.

Answer (score 1):

No has terminado de entender cómo funciona la gestión de la memoria dinámica:

Aquí estás reservando memoria para un entero:

```
int *paci = new int[1];
```

Esta memoria la pierdes a continuación, ya que reasignas el puntero sin liberar la memoria reservada previamente

```
for(int i=0;i<3; i++){
    paci= new int[hosp[i]]; // redmimensiono vector
```

Por cierto, nota que el comentario está mal. No estás redimensionando el vector sino solicitando una reserva nueva de memoria. Redimensionar implicaría reutilizar la memoria anterior o, en su defecto, conservar los datos que ya tuviese ... ni lo uno ni lo otro.

Además, fíjate que el bucle hace 3 pasadas, y en cada pasada sobreescribes el puntero `paci`. El resultado es que, al final, el puntero *apuntará* a la última reserva de memoria que has hecho, que tendrá capacidad para 7 elementos.

A ver, te están pidiendo rellenar los datos de 3 hospitales, cada uno con su propio conjunto de valores ... esto son dos dimensiones (id_del_hospital, id_del_valor). Es decir, necesitas **un puntero doble**

```
int **paci = new int*[3];
```

Con esto reservas espacios para 3 punteros de tipo `int`.

El siguiente paso es conseguir que esos punteros direccionen memoria válida:

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    paci[i] = new int[hosp[i]];
}
```

Por otro lado, el error que comentas se produce porque `matriz` tiene inicialmente capacidad para almacenar un único puntero de tipo `int`:

```
int **matriz = new int *[1];
```

Y además dicho puntero **no está inicializado**, luego apunta a memoria que no te pertenece. Cualquier intento de acceso a dicha memoria será detectado por el Sistema Operativo, que procederá a matar tu programa para evitar que corrompas la memoria de otros procesos.

A la hora de hacer la reserva tienes que indicar la capacidad que necesitas, justo como en el ejemplo que te he puesto antes con `paci`... aquí no te puedo decir cómo proceder porque la descripción que das del enunciado es demasiado vaga y en ella no se identifica cual es el uso real que necesitas darle a `matriz`